# There are at least: $\big\lfloor\sqrt{p_{n}}\big\rfloor(p_{n}-1)-|p_{n}-2n|+1$, primes less than $p_{n}^{2}$, where $p_{n}$ is the $n$-th prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, sieve-theory

> There are at least: $\big\lfloor\sqrt{p_{n}}\big\rfloor(p_{n}-1)-|p_{n}-2n|+1$, primes less than $p_{n}^{2}$, where $p_{n}$ is the $n$-th prime?

Is this true or false? If true, how does one prove it?

I made this observation just an hour ago and I checked it thoroughly and carefully. The accuracy often seems very promising as far as I checked. Again I have no idea as to how to approach a proof.

Comment: It's not clear how you could observe it "thoroughly" without a proof :)

Comment: Have you seen (I think Erdos's) proof that there are at least $\frac{1}{2}\log_2 p_n$ primes? Could be related.

Comment: I always accept any answer that that is somewhat elementary and easy to understand and sometimes I upvote the answer as a consent. @NicoDean

Comment: Perhaps I should say "heuristically" in that case. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: For $x=p_n^2$, your claim is approximately that $\pi(x)\ge x^{3/4}$, approximately. Comparing  with $\pi(x)\sim \frac x{\ln x}$, your inequality certainly holds for $x$ big enough, namely as soon as both $\sqrt[4]x>\ln x$ **and** the $\sim$ is sufficiently tight.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Guess I need to study more about "The Prime Number Theorem" and other theorems/inequalities concerning the density of prime. @HagenvonEitzen